USB does not recognize when I plug in small micro chips such as ESP8266, ESP32, F7 and H7 Flight controller
This is a new PC Built with AMD Ryzen 7 7700X 8-Core processor, ASUS TUF GAMING B650-PLUS WIFI AMD B650 AM5 Ryzen™ Desktop 9000 8000 and 7000 ATX motherboard.
I've installed Ububntu 24 LTS, then (Pro) for home use.
I do a lot of tinkering with micro controllers with Arduino.IDE and Micropython.
Ubuntu does not recognize any of my micro controllers when I plug in a micro controller.
I am using the USB ports from the motherboard, not the case.
I'm not sure if this is an AMD or Ubuntu issue.  I really don't want to go back to Windows!
Please: HELP!   TIA

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
